# I am trying to create image slider.On setting display flex the flex-shrinks even if flex-grow is given?

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML CSS. I am practicing to make a website.I am trying to create an image slider. On setting `display: flex` the flex-shrinks even if `flex-grow` is given?

For that I took a div container(class name is content) and inside that I took 3 other div container(class name is inner-content). After setting css properties for those 3 containers and if I set `display:flex` on outer div container the flex shrinks. I don't want that. I tried `flex-basis` but it doesn't work?

/*=======Image before applying display:flex;===*/
[image]

/*=======Image after applying display:flex;===*/
[image]

```css
.content{
margin-top: 10px;
display:flex;
height:85vh;
background: yellow;
width: 100%;
/* overflow: hidden; */
padding:0px;
}
.inner-content{
    padding:75px 50px 0px;
    display:flex;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.cont{
    flex:1.5;
    padding:90px 0px 0px 50px;
    background: chocolate;
}
.cont h3{
    font-size:30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-shadow: 1px 0px black;  
}
.cont p{
    font-size:20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;

}
.cont button{
    width:150px;
    margin:auto;
    height:11%;
    margin-top:10px;
    font-size:18px;
    border:2px solid #072085;
    color:#072085;
    background: white;
    border-radius:20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.image-container{
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1;
    flex:1;
}
.image-container img{
    max-width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    margin:0 auto;
    animation:drop 1.5s ease;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="main-page">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="inner-content">
                <div class="cont">
                    <h3>Redmi Note 8</h3>
                    <p>48MP AI rear camera with Sony IMX586 camera sensor</p>
                    <button href="#">BUY NOW</button>
                </div>
                <div class="image-container">
                    <img src="1.png"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!----2nd-->
            <div class="inner-content">
                <div class="cont">
                    <h3>Redmi Note 8</h3>
                    <p>48MP AI rear camera with Sony IMX586 camera sensor</p>
                    <button href="#">BUY NOW</button>
                </div>
                <div class="image-container">
                    <img src="1.png"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!----3rd-->
            <div class="inner-content">
                <div class="cont">
                    <h3>Redmi Note 8</h3>
                    <p>48MP AI rear camera with Sony IMX586 camera sensor</p>
                    <button href="#">BUY NOW</button>
                </div>
                <div class="image-container">
                    <img src="1.png"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give min-width to your `inner-content`. Run the snippet and check in full page.

I am assuming you know how to implement slider functionality.

```css
.content{
  margin-top: 10px;
  display:flex;
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  padding:0px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.inner-content{
    padding:75px 50px 0px;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid black;
    min-width: 90vw;
}

.cont{
    padding:90px 0px 0px 50px;
    background: chocolate;
}

.cont h3{
    font-size:30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-shadow: 1px 0px black;  
}
.cont p{
    font-size:20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;

}
.cont button{
    width:150px;
    margin:auto;
    height:11%;
    margin-top:10px;
    font-size:18px;
    border:2px solid #072085;
    color:#072085;
    background: white;
    border-radius:20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.image-container{
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1;
    flex:1;
}
.image-container img{
    max-width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    margin:0 auto;
    animation:drop 1.5s ease;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="main-page">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="inner-content">
                <div class="cont">
                    <h3>Redmi Note 8</h3>
                    <p>48MP AI rear camera with Sony IMX586 camera sensor</p>
                    <button href="#">BUY NOW</button>
                </div>
                <div class="image-container">
                    <img src="https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-70348099,width-320,resizemode-4,imgv-5/Xiaomi-Redmi-Note-8-Pro.jpg"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!----2nd-->
            <div class="inner-content">
                <div class="cont">
                    <h3>Redmi Note 8</h3>
                    <p>48MP AI rear camera with Sony IMX586 camera sensor</p>
                    <button href="#">BUY NOW</button>
                </div>
                <div class="image-container">
                    <img src="https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-70348099,width-320,resizemode-4,imgv-5/Xiaomi-Redmi-Note-8-Pro.jpg"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!----3rd-->
            <div class="inner-content">
                <div class="cont">
                    <h3>Redmi Note 8</h3>
                    <p>48MP AI rear camera with Sony IMX586 camera sensor</p>
                    <button href="#">BUY NOW</button>
                </div>
                <div class="image-container">
                    <img src="https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-70348099,width-320,resizemode-4,imgv-5/Xiaomi-Redmi-Note-8-Pro.jpg"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```